# How to show a dialog inside the method onTimeSet?

Tags: android, timepicker

I want to know if the values of timerMinute and timerSecond are set when I choose these values from my TimePicker.

```
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int minute, int second) {
        // Do something with the time chosen by the user
        this.timerMinute = minute;
        this.timerSecond = second;
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Minute: " + minute, 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

I want to show a dialog inside the method onTimeSet and show the values choosen.

I've used Toast to show the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what framework you are using, are you using Fragments? You want to call `Activity#showDialog(int)` or use the FragmentManager to create a DialogFragment.

But here is the most basic approach:

```
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builer(this);
    builder.setMessage("You chose " + hourOfDay + ":" + minute).show();
}
```

Notice the parameters are hours and minutes (no seconds).

Comment: Thank you. I've used Toast. I just want to show the parameters. I know the parameters are hour and minute, but I think I can handle them the way I like. Am I wrong?

Comment: Well, hours only go up to 23 (at most) but minutes and seconds go to 59... However you can easily create a dialog with a custom layout to do this, especially if you can use the NumperPicker widget (API 11+).